# What is the most elegant way to pick a random value from a set defined in NS_OPTION in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, enums, bitmask, arc4random

I have an NS_OPTION that I'm defining as such :

```
 typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, PermittedSize) {
  SmallSize = 1 << 0,
  MediumSize = 1 << 1,
  LargeSize = 1 << 2
 };
```

And later I set the values I need :

```
 PermittedSize size = SmallSize | MediumSize;
```

I'm using it to randomly generate an various objects of small and medium sizes(duh) for a particular level of a game.
What is the best way to go about selecting which size of an object to generate? Meaning, I'd like  to choose randomly for each object I'm generating whether it will be one of the 2 options allowed (small and medium in this case). Normally I would use an arc4random function with the range of numbers I need - but in this case, how can it be done with bits? (and then mapped back to the values of the PermittedSize type?

Answer (score 2):

Use the result from arc4random to determine the amount of bit shifting you want to do.  Something like this:

```
int bitShiftAmount = arc4random_uniform(numberOfPermittedSizes);
PermittedSize size = 1 << bitShiftAmount;
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps, but now I'm having trouble getting the correct values. I have size defined as follows:  `PermittedSize size = SmallSize | LargeSize;` then, I add this to a hashtable of rules with a string key; I later retrieve the value, and unwrap it as follows :  `PermittedSize sizes = (PermittedSize) [self.rules getSizeRules];
    int bitShiftAmount = arc4random_uniform(sizes);
    PermittedSize actualSize = 1 << bitShiftAmount;`
When I test the values thus : if ( actualSize & SmallSize )
        NSLog(@"small"); etc medium is returned - the only one not desired. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong.  I misunderstood your question.  I guess if it were up to me, I would make things explicit and store an array of permitted sizes instead of a single value.  Then I would randomly pick an element out of the array.  I know it doesn't use your bitmask, but it just makes more sense to me.  Something like this: `NSArray *sizes = [self.rules.getSizeRules]; int sizeIndex = arc4random_uniform([sizes count]); PermittedSize sizeToUse = [[sizes objectAtIndex:sizeIndex] intValue];`  Where the elements of sizes are NSNumbers for one of the values of PermittedSize.

Comment: ok, thank you Jonathan. That was my thought as well, but I figured since I'm a newbie in objective-c there might be a nifty and elegant solution wasn't thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

You are still working with integers. `SmallSize` is 1. `MediumSize` is 2. And `LargeSize` is `4`.

So pick a random number from 1 to 3. 1 is small, 2 is medium, 3 is both.

Once you have a random number, assign it.

```
NSInteger val = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1; // give 1-3
PermittedSize size = (PermittedSize)val;
```